# Problem with rostopic

Tags: c++, message, ros-electric, husky, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've created my own message type, and have a C++ program generating messages. When I attempt to listen to the messages using rostopic echo in my PC, then I get perfect values.

Then I tried to enter into Husky A200 by ssh ing and then executing a subscriber program which subscibes to my topic.

> ssh administrator@cpr-sal-01
> Then typed password and entered into Husky

> roscd face_subscriber   (where i have my subscriber code)

> rosrun face_subscriber face_subscriber   (my face_subscriber code)

The problem is that my topic is not found in rostopic list of Husky. This subscriber code works perfectly in my pC. What should I do to make my topic get in the rostopic list of Husky ?

PS - I have electric running in my system and Husky has Feurte running in it. (

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42886/problem-with-rostopic/) by [Arjun PE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2019/arjun-pe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like your network isn't setup properly. Before you run you own code, you should try with rostopic echo to eliminate error sources.

Where is you core running? Can you see other topics from the remote machine? Is the ROS_MASTER_URI and possible ROS_IP/HOSTNAME set correctly? If that all works, your topics should also come up.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5